# Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object admin blank page after trying to upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9

I get this error

```
"Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object admin blank page"
```

Also the admin page is blank, so what could be the issue.
I tried deleting all cache from /var/cache folder already! Tried disabling all the modules by renaming all those xml files.

I tried to check the magento installation by using magento-check.php and it shows http://prntscr.com/6v3ny3

PHP version: http://prntscr.com/6v3och

Comment: check `var/log/` and `var/report` for any issues. Also you can enable developer mode and error reporting in `index.php`

Comment: I got this error message from the logs. And I already enabled devloper mode and error reporting. Also I tried increasing the memory. This whole this happend after I used magento-connect manager to update the addons!

Comment: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/91985359245/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a

Comment: Have a look through http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 see if you can find the reason :)